# Bitlocker Encrypted Thumb Drive Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bitlocker

for backup purposes I encrypted two mirrored thumb drives with bitlocker.

I usually leave them plugged in and they have been working fine until I rebooted my PC.

Now a [image] notification keeps flashing repeatedly when I insert the drive.

When I click it, it shows an error

[image]

I tried to plug it into another computer but it shows the same behaviour. So the stick got corrupted somehow.

Is there anything I can do to recover it?

Comment: Thumb drives are by nature unreliable/volatile.  I doubt there is anything you can do beyond hiring a recovery service.  I do wish you luck finding an answer to this.

Comment: BTW, you might use third-party encryption, e.g., Veracrypt or 7-Zip, in the future to see if it's any more reliable -- but if the USB device itself is damaged, data is unlikely to be salvageable.

Comment: The thing is I made two copies of them, what are the chances both break at the same time. Which is what left me wondering what caused this.

Comment: You write that you leave them plugged in. So the chance is high that whatever happens to one can also happen to the second.